# Primefaces Chips Web Component - Properties

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using the new Primefaces 6.2 RC and I need to change its size.

I set the size as below, but the component stays the same size:

```
<p:chips size="800"/>
```

or:

```
<p:chips style="width: 400px; height: 800px"/>
```

Does anyone knows how can I change its size?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Chips</title>
    <style type="text/css">
.ui-chips {
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-chips-container {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body style="background-color:red">
    <h:form>
        <p:chips />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Solution 2 :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Chips</title>
    <style type="text/css">
.ui-chips-container {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body style="background-color:red">
    <h:form>
        <p:chips style="width:100%" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I have raised a issue to confirm with primefaces team https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2249.

As far as i see the style=100% get applied to a DIV of ui-chips.

[image: Style 100%]

In the next line

ui-chips-container has a default width of 400px which come via components.css
This causes the input(chips) field to remain at 400px.

Option 3 : As per Primefaces team
I see what you mean. I think to be most flexible an inputStyle + inputStyleClass would need to be added as well as a chipStyle and chipStyleClass to custom style the chi labels themselves.
If you need to accomplish this right now you can do it pretty easily with CSS.

```
<style>
.chip-width > .ui-chips-container {
   width: 800px;
}
</style>
And in your XHTML.

<p:chips id="chips" styleClass="chip-width"/>
```

Comment: I've tested your solution, some properties worked, but the size of the component stays the same, no matter if I change its `width`. Any hint?

Comment: Also just to be sure  clear cache and test. i set default for IE to "delete browser history on exit"

Comment: I've been using this set on Mozilla for a long time already, but that issue you covered is not related to the problem. I used ` <p:chips style="width: 1000px"/> ` or  ` <p:chips style="width: 100%"/> `, but the component stays at the same size. I also updated it directly on the CSS, but also stays the same.

Comment: i have updated my answer. Do let me know if this works for you. If you check via Mozilla (F12) you will find ui-chips-container has 400px as a default width which comes from the components.css.