# How to style a PrimeNG Chips?

Tags: css, angular

I have a `form` in my application where I use the following code from Primafaces:

```
...other inputs...

<label for="workshopTags">Tags</label>
<p-chips
    [(ngModel)]="values"
    name="workshopTags"
    id="workshopTags"
></p-chips>
```

I am able to display the Chip element correctly but I would like to style it putting its width to 100% and the height to 100px, but nothing seems to work to change those. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216268/primefaces-chips-web-component-properties/43217778) didn't work for me. I tried to set a styleClass or an inline style as [the documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chips) suggest but they didn't work either. If I write inline:

```
style="width: 100%"
```

The following error is thrown:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'width: 100%;'

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try inspecting the resulting DOM from `<p-chips>` component. You won't be able to style it directly because of css encapsulation.

To be able to style inner DOM of custom components, you either need to set ViewEncapsulation to None, or use global style sheets.

Comment: Thanks, mine was a dummy error: I was using the property "styleClass" while I needed "inputStyleClass". That solved.

Comment: If you want to target specific elements, look at the bottom of the documentation and you will see the list of classes. And yes inputStyleClass was a way to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are tow methos to style primeng component overwrite the original style or by create a custom style base on custome class

*overwrite*

add the style to global `style.css` or `style.scss` , this method for overwrite primeng component style without add extra class to the component.

```
.ui-chips {
  display: inline-block
}

.ui-chips ul {
  border:2px dashed green !important; /*  I have use important */
}

 .ui-chips > ul.ui-inputtext .ui-chips-token {
    font-size: 14px;
    background: green !important; /*  I have use important */
    border:1px solid #005555;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #ccc;
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-jncs4r)

*custome style*

the method above will change the style of all p-chips component in the entier project , by this method you need to set styleClass property so you can create different style like the example here  , but you need to set styleClass property **for every component**

```
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="values" styleClass="p-chips"></p-chips>
```

style.css

```
.p-chips.ui-chips {
  /* border:1px solid #ff2200; */
  display: inline-block
}

.p-chips.ui-chips ul {
  border:2px dashed orange;
}

 .p-chips.ui-chips > ul.ui-inputtext .ui-chips-token {
    font-size: 14px;
    background: orange;
    border:1px solid #ff5555;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #ccc;
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-jd4v2m)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ht **/deep/ modifier** ,add this inside your **app.component.css** and delete it from your style.css, and you don't need **!important** to force the style here, delete it. here is what you are looking for

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

/deep/  .p-chips > .ui-inputtext {
  width: 100%;
  height:  100px;
}
```

check it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-kmm7xw

Comment: this will affect others components check this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-startup-pomrp9

Comment: update the style like this to solve it `/deep/ .p-chips >.ui-inputtext {...}` 

Answer (score 0):

You could try encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in your override component decorator:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-chip',
   templateUrl: 'path-to-template where you use ui-chips',
   styleUrls: ['path-to-styles where you could override ui-chips styles'],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppChipComponent { }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the width to 100%, you have to use the `style` or `styleClass` attribute and set the css property `display: block`.

As an example using the `styleClass` attribute

```
<p-chips
    [(ngModel)]="interests"
    styleClass="block">
</p-chips>
```

Here I am using **Prime Flex v3** with **PrimeNg**.